# Qt eglfs backend without kms/drm

Tags: qt, opengl-es, embedded, xserver, egl

I see that `eglfs` can be used without `kms/drm`, at least it's not its default backend. I thought you needed `kms/drm` to access the gpu without an X server.
How does `egl` in `eglfs` manages then to talk to the gpu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMS is the VC4 mesa driver being develop for Raspberry pi by anholt (https://github.com/anholt/mesa/wiki/VC4), the point is to replace the actual opengl driver from broadcom, which is closed source, and if possible, improve it.

Without kms/drm, the egl in eglfs use the broadcom driver to handle opengl widgets.

Actually, is supposed that the kms/drm should work better, however, I'm getting better performance running with the broadcom driver, I'm still testing my build.

Of course, we are talking about raspberry pi (3 in my case).